# Database strategy for concurrent read/write operation in it

Tags: performance, design-patterns, database-design, domain-driven-design

I have 6 services talking to the same database SQL Server 2016 (Payments) where some services are doing write operations and some are doing read operations. Database server holds other databases as well than Payments database. We do not have any archival job in place on Payments database. We recently got 99% CPU usage and as well as memory issue on database server.

Obvious steps I can take including

1. Create archival jobs to migrate old data to archived database
2. Can scale up database server.

But still want to explore other best solutions. I have below questions.

1. Can we make different databases for read and write operations, if yes how?
2. Can we migrate data on the fly to NoSql database from RDBMS because it is faster for read operation?
3. What is the best design for such applications where concurrent read and write operations happens?

Answer (score 2):

Storage is all about trade-offs, so it is extremely tricky to find correct "storage" solution without diving deep in different aspects such as latency, availability, concurrency, access pattern and security requirements. In this particular case, payments data is being stored which should be confidential and straightforward removes some storage solutions. In general, you should

1. Cache the read data, but if the same data is being modified
   constantly this will not work. Caching also doesn't work well when
   your reads are not public (i.e., can not be reused across multiple
   read calls, preferrably across multiple users), which is possible in this case as we are dealing with payments data.
2. Read/write master database and read-only slaves pattern is also "common" pattern to scale reads. It doesn't scale the writes though. It again depends if the application can work with "replication lag".
3. Sharding is the common access pattern to scale writes. It comes with other burden of cross node query aggregation etc (in some databases).
4. Finally, based on the data access pattern, refactor the schema
   and employ different databases. CQRS (Command Query Responsibility
   Segregation) is one way to achieve it, but it comes at it has its
   own pros and cons. For more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs

Few years back, I read this book which helped me immensely in understanding these concepts: [https://www.amazon.com/Scalability-Startup-Engineers-Artur-Ejsmont/dp/0071843655](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071843655)